# Build URL in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to build a request with `HttpRequestBuilder` in ktor. I don't understand how I pass in the url. I would logically imagine we would pass in `.url("https://url.com")` as one of the items in the builder along with a few other things then call `.build()`, but the [API docs](https://api.ktor.io/0.9.5/io.ktor.client.request/-http-request-builder/) say that the url function is meant to be passed in as `fun url(block: URLBuilder.(URLBuilder) -> Unit): Unit`.

Can someone help me understand how to pass in `URLBuilder.(URLBuilder) -> Unit` with an example please? I don't quite understand what it's trying to ask me to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

The url() function you're referring to requires you to pass in an extension function of URLBuilder. For example:

```
val builder = HttpRequestBuilder()
builder.url {
    protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
    host = "stackoverflow.com"
    encodedPath = "/somePath"
}
val request = builder.build()
```